# A problem on Arithmetic Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $V_r$ denote the sum of first $r$ terms of an Arithmetic Progression whose first term is $r$  and the common difference is $2r-1$. Let $T_r=V_{r+1}-V_r-2$ and $Q_r=T_{r+1}-T_r$ for $r=1,2,...$.

1. $T_r$ is always

a. an odd number.

b. an  even number.

c. a prime number.

d. a composite number.

$\;\;$2. Which of the following is a correct statement?

a. $Q_1, Q_2, Q_3,...$ are in AP with common difference 5.

b. $Q_1, Q_2, Q_3,...$ are in AP with common difference 6.

c. $Q_1, Q_2, Q_3,...$ are in AP with common difference 11.

d. $Q_1=Q_2=Q_3=...$

My approach:

Sum of $(r+1)$ terms - Sum of $(r)$ terms = $(r+1)^{th}$ term

$\therefore V_{r+1}-V_r=t_{r+1}$

$t_{r+1}=r+(r)(2r-1)=2r^2$

$\therefore T_r=2r^2-2r=2r(r-1)$

Thus, $T_r$ is always even.

Now for evaluating $T_{r+1}$, I put $r+1$ in the place of $r$ in the expression of $T_{r}$

Doing so, I got $Q_r$ as $4r$, which is an AP with common difference 4. Where am I going wrong?

According to the book, the answers are:

1.- d.

2.- b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an AP with first term $a$ and common difference $d$, sum of $n$ terms is given as:
$$S_n=\frac n2[2a+(n-1)d]$$

$$\displaystyle \therefore V_r=\frac r2\left[2r+(r-1)(2r-1)\right]$$

$$\displaystyle V_{r+1}=\frac {r+1}2\left[2(r+1)+r(2r+1)\right]$$

$$\displaystyle \therefore V_{r+1}-V_r-2=(3r-1)(r+1)$$

$$\therefore T_r=(3r-1)(r+1)$$

Thus, $T_r$ is always a composite number.

$$Q_r=T_{r+1}-T_r$$
$$\therefore Q_r=[(3r+2)(r+2)]-[(3r-1)(r+1)]$$
$$\therefore Q_r=6r+5$$

Thus, $Q_1, Q_2,Q_3,\cdots$ are in AP with common difference $6$.

Answer (score 0):

Where you are going wrong is to assume that $V_{r+1}$  is the $(r+1)^{\text{th}}$ sum of the same series that $V_r$ is the $r^{\text{th}}$ sum of.  It is the $(r+1)^{\text{th}}$ sum of the series that starts with $r+1$ and has difference $2r+1$.  What you should do is calculate $V_r$ in terms of $r$.  You can use that to get $V_{r+1}$ and subtract.

Comment: Well, I tried that. It gave $T_r=3r^2+1$. The series of $T_r$ then becomes 1, 13, 28, 49,...

Comment: The series of $T_r$ is not a particular one of odd or even or prime or composite numbers. So, are we going wrong again?

Comment: I get $V_r=r^2+(2r-1)\sum_{i=0}^{r-1}i=r^2+(2r-1)r(r-1)/2=r^3+\frac 12(-r^2+r), T_r=3r^2+2r+1$, which gives $1,6,19\dots $  I don't like any of the choices

Comment: $T_r=V_{r+1}-V_r-2r$, so you finally get $T_r=3r^2+1$. At some points (like $r=2,6,etc.$), $T_r$ gives a prime number. So, I guess, there is something wrong in the question itself. However, if we assume indeed $T_r=3r^2+1$, then we get $Q_r=6r+3$ which is an AP with common difference 6.